# Tomcat context.xml resource password not allow special charcaters

Tags: tomcat6

I have been trying for add data source in tomcat conf/context.xml as below.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DS1"
                        auth="Container"
                        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
                        url="jdbc:sqlserver://121.111.11.91;databaseName=DB_NAME"
                        username="testUanme"
                        password="TT&123$"
                        maxPoolSize="50"
                        removeAbandoned="true"
                        removeAbandonedTimeout="1000"
                        logAbandoned="true"
                        />
```

After set Data Source entry in config file i m restarting tomcat and it gives error like:

The reference to entity "TT" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Password not allowing special characters which i have used & and $.

Please suggest what should be there which allows me to enter special characters in password..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you replace `&` in your password with `&amp;` you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Mark Thanks for quick response. actually i have used "&amp;" or "&#38;" for "&" and "&dollar;" or "&#36;" for "$" ,but still connection issue is coming.

Comment: I've tested &amp; and it works for me. Maybe if you provide the full error message (with stacktrace) and make sure that you are using exactly the example quoted above then some light will be shone on this issue.

Comment: Hi Mark...Now it is working for me..something was wrong with credential..Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Hey @MarkThomas, can we use the same "&amp;"  in application.properties file?

Comment: No.  `&amp;` is an XML character reference.  A `.properties` file is not XML.  (The syntax for `.properties` files is documented in the `Properties` javadoc.)